# Ubuntu 15.10: Firefox can connect to internet on corporate network, but system services cannot

Tags: firefox, internet, proxy

I am running Ubuntu 15.10. I can see that i am able to access internet through firefox when I allow 'Auto detect proxy settings for this network' but the system services, like apt-get, etc. are unable to connect to the internet. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually configure your proxy server for `apt-get`. First check what is the address of the server, then type:

```
sudo echo 'Acquire::http::proxy "http://<proxy>:<port>";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

Replace `<proxy>` and `<port>` with your settings.

To add proxy for HTTPS and FTP protocols use (mind the double character `>>`):

```
sudo echo 'Acquire::https::proxy "https://<proxy>:<port>";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf
sudo echo 'Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://<proxy>:<port>";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

If your proxy server requires authentication, precede the address with username and password according to your settings.

---

Your `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file should look like this in the end:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>";
```